# Cycling through the *Buffer List* with C-n, C-p

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to use the `C-n` or `C-p` shortcuts (or some other shortcut) in the *Buffer List* to cycle through the list of buffers?

Currently when I get to the top (or bottom) of that list it doesn't cycle through forcing me to change direction and then having to go through what might be a very long buffer list.

Alternatively, are there any other useful shortcuts I might be able to use to navigate the *Buffer List* more quickly?

Below's a typical situation I am faced with:

[image]

Comment: You may want to use one of the enhanced buffer lists. See [How do I switch buffers quickly?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/728/how-do-i-switch-buffers-quickly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>M-<</kbd> and <kbd>M-></kbd> should jump to the very beginning and end of a buffer.